# Trig and Radians Confusion

Tags: trigonometry

I am learning about radians in my current class and am totally confused.

How does $\sin(x+\frac\pi 2)=\cos(x)$ when $\frac\pi 2<x$ < $\pi$.

I drew the triangles and I got

$\sin(x+\frac\pi 2)=\frac{-\mathrm{opposite}}{-\mathrm{hypotenuse}}=\frac{\mathrm{opp}}{\mathrm{hyp}}$

$\cos(x)=\frac{\mathrm{adjacent}}{\mathrm{hypotenuse}}$

If the adjacent equals the hypotenuse this should work however in most circumstances this isn't true.  What is the major flaw in my work??

Here is what I drew out.

[image]

Comment: It's tough to answer without seeing your diagram.  Are you making sure all your triangles have the "adjacent" line pointing left or right on the x-axis, and the "opposite" line pointing up or down?

Comment: First things first. $\pi$ (pi) is number, whereas 'pie' is a dessert.

Comment: @NovaDenizen What would to correct diagram look like? Could u put a pic :)  I will try to post one of mine

Comment: ooops I got so confused with the greater and less thans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression for $\sin(x)$ is correct.  But recall that the cosine is the abscissa divided by the radius of the circle.  So in your drawing, $\cos(x)=\frac a b$.

[image]

Comment: Can you look at the pic I drew :) I think there prob is something wrong wth that because that is what I went by.

Comment: but isn't cosine adjacent over hypotenuse? Isn't c the adjacent side?

Comment: The triangle should be drawn so that the terminal side is from its intersection with the circle to the horizontal axis.  Give me some time to draw it.

Comment: Please note that your notation could be a source of confusion.  Note that the values of the numerators and denominators could be negative.  If you're still thinking in terms of triangles, you might think that $a$ and $c$ are always positive (because they're the lengths of sides).  But for your drawing of the angle $x$, note that $a<0$ (on the left) and $c>0$ (on the top).  Also, for your drawing of angle $x+\frac\pi 2$, note that $a<0$ (on the bottom) and $c<0$ (on the left).

Answer (score 0):

It's just how it is, if you look at a graph of sine and overlay cosine on top of it, then this would be readily apparent.